# Wait cursor on submiting a POST form

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I want loading cursor on submiting excel to database through a submit form. Function takes some time. I use jQuery to POST:

```
function SubmitForm(form) {
    $('*').css('cursor', 'wait');
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: form.action,
        data: $(form).serialize(),
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.success) {
                Popup.dialog('close');
                location.reload(true);
            }
            else {
                Popup.html(data);
                SubmitForm(form);
            }
        }
    });
    $('*').css('cursor', 'default');
    return false;
};
```

Can someone point out why the `cursor: wait` doesn't work?

Comment: Instead of using * as a selector, can't you use "body" or "html" ? Maybe try with "!important" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting `cursor: wait` is working fine. The problem is because the you immediately set `cursor: default` again as the AJAX request is asynchronous, and you don't wait for it to finish.

To fix this, move the logic which resets the cursor in the the `complete` handler:

```js
function SubmitForm(form) {
  $('body').css('cursor', 'wait');

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: form.action,
    data: $(form).serialize(),
    success: function(data) {
      if (data.success) {
        Popup.dialog('close');
        location.reload(true);
      } else {
        Popup.html(data);
        SubmitForm(form);
      }
    },
    complete: function() {
      $('body').css('cursor', 'default');
    }
  });

  return false;
};
```

Also note the use of `body` in the selector instead of `*`, as this performs much better and should do the same job.

Comment: I have two popup forms, first: edit, which is a simple update operation for one instance in database and your solution works for this one. And the second popup form: import, which reads excel and bulk uploads data to the database, for this one it doesn't work. Both popups redirect to the POST method, the only difference is that action from the first popup form uses model binding. Any idea why it doesn't work?

Comment: Without seeing an example it's hard to say, but this pattern should work for any asynchronous request, no matter the location it's calling or data being sent.